# "I gave it everything I've got" or "I gave everything I've got"

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, difference, relative-clauses

Last day, I read this sentence " Nice game, the team gave **IT** everything they've got" 
to give is a transitive verb therefore An object must follow the verb; however I consider "everything they've got" the object of the sentence so there's no need to put IT in the sentence....

so what's going on here ?

Answer (score 2):

Kentaro Tomono's answer is partially correct.  In this case, "everything (they've got)" is the direct object, and "it" is an indirect object.  The sentence:

> They gave it everything they've got.

could be reworded as:

> They gave everything they've got to it.

(although most people wouldn't actually say it that way)

In this case, the implied "it" is actually "the game" being discussed, so this is equivalent to:

> They gave the game everything they've got.

Saying the sentence with and without "it" are both OK, and are roughly interchangeable, though without the "it" the feeling is a little more vague, and is basically saying "they expended a lot of effort", whereas with the "it" it is emphasizing that all the effort they expended was definitely focussed on trying to win the game, and not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer even though I am not a native speaker!. So please ignore or downvote mine if you would like to.

Your question is very confusing since the contents of the title and the contents of the question you are asking is different.

If that **IT** is an ***indirect object***, then it is OK, except that the following phrase after the "everything", which is "they've got" should be "it's got". ( Though I don't understand the sentence what it means without prior context. ). So I assume there is some error made by the writer, and

> so what's going on here ?

Either the writer might have tried to say "I gave **them** everything **they've got**" or "I gave them everything **it** ( probably referring to the word "team" ) **has got(ten)**".